# Zipping the 10 most recent files

Tags: linux, files, date, zip

Basically my requirement is to find 10 latest logs and compress it into zip. I have tried  command `ls -Lt | head -10 | zip log.zip *.log`, but output is not matched.

Comment: Did you consider using 'logrotate' with a dedicated schedule? You are able to specify how old the files may get before being compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First **take backup**

You should try:

```
ls -Lt | head -10 | xargs zip log.zip
```

Your command

```
zip log.zip *.log
```

is trying to compress every file in the current directory which is ending with `.log`, it is not taking file names from STDIN.

If your directory has mixed files, i.e. files other than log files, then you can try:

```
ls -Lt *.log | head -10 | xargs zip log.zip
```

Comment: thanks , ls -Lt | head -10 | xargs zip log.zip  here zip is created in same directory i want that zip is goes to different directory so how can specify with this command]

Comment: Instead of log.zip use the absolute path like `/home/username/...../log.zip`.

Comment: be warned that if any of the filenames (ever) contain spaces, tabs, or newlines, then they will be mangled and lost in the current pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

To safely select the 10 most recent (plain) files in the current directory, I would recommend `zsh`, since it can safely, natively, select files based on modification time:

```
zsh -c 'zip log.zip *.log(.om[1,10])'
```

This uses two of zsh's wildcard ("glob") qualifiers and a subscripting operator:

- `*.log( ... )` -- this starts the wildcard off with `*.log`, which will select every<sup>1</sup> file in the current directory that ends with `.log`, filtered by the following criteria
- `.` -- this filters the resulting list to include only plain files
- `om` -- this sorts ("orders") the resulting list by modification time, most recent first
- `[1,10]` -- this narrows the resulting list by selecting elements 1 through 10 (the ten most recent files)

Once zsh has generated the 10 most recent plain files, it hands those to the `zip` command.

---

Footnotes:

1. by default, zsh will not select hidden (dot) files, such as `.foo.log`; if you have such files *and* wish to select them, you can include the `D` glob qualifier (`*.log(.Dom[1,10])`) or set the `GLOB_DOTS` option (with `setopt globdots`).

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command

```
ls -ltrh| awk '$1 ~ /-rw/{print $0}'|sed -n '1,10p'| awk '{print "zip" " " $NF".zip" " " $NF}'| sh
```

Comment: Please don't try to parse ls. Besides the usual trouble, what if the file(s) aren't writable by the user-- causing the /-rw/ to fail?