# keep 2 newest files on folder and delete others

Tags: linux, shell

I have a backup folder on my server with autogenerated files. They are consuming 100% of my disk. So i need to create a cron that delete all files but keep the 2 newest.

I have found a code that might do that but dont know how to run it.

```
(temp_all=$(mktemp) && temp_last=$(mktemp) && { tac | tee $temp_all | sort -un > $temp_last ; } && grep -vf $temp_last $temp_all ; rm -f $temp_last $temp_all)
```

What should i do? Create a .sh file and runs it with parameter? How would i do that?

This code will do what i need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If zsh is installed on your system, it has some nice glob qualifiers for this kind of thing - see for example [Zipping the 10 most recent files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506273/65304)

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` and `perl` (**use with caution**, `unlink` delete files):

(can handle files of all sort: with newlines, spaces...)

```
$ ls -ltr
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stardust stardust 0 févr. 14 00:21 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stardust stardust 0 févr. 14 00:21 bar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stardust stardust 0 févr. 14 00:21 base
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stardust stardust 0 févr. 14 00:21 qux

$ find /path/to/dir -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | 
      sort -z -nk1 |
      perl -0 -ne '
          m|\s+(\./.*)|ms and push(@files, $1);
          END{unlink for @files[0..($#files - 2)]}'

$ ls -ltr
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stardust stardust 0 févr. 14 00:21 base
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stardust stardust 0 févr. 14 00:21 qux
```

---

##### To use in crontab:

Create a script (just copy & paste in a shell):

```
install -D -m755 /dev/null ~/bin/remove_files_except_2_last_ones
cat<<EOF > ~/bin/remove_files_except_2_last_ones
#!/bin/sh

. ~/.bashrc # or any other *rc file, to set PATH variable

find /path/to/dir -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | 
    sort -z -nk1 |
    perl -0 -ne '
        m|\s+(\./.*)|ms and push(@files, $1);
        END{unlink for @files[0..($#files - 2)]}'    
EOF
crontab -e
```

Then paste :

```
* * * * * ~/bin/remove_files_except_2_last_ones &>/tmp/2_last_ones.log
```

(change `* * * * *`  with your own time specs).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry because im a newby on this. How can i run it in a crontab?

Comment: Check my edited post.